# Call a derived class's method through the base class's ptr

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a new class (`QMdiSubWindowMod` that inherits from `QMdiSubWindow`) to pass a pointer array throw a window (each of these window have a different pointer array). Then, I don't have any problem to set this array of pointer because I set it right after the creation of the `QMdiSubWindowMod`.

My problem is that I want to change some property of object into these array so I need to call a `QMdiSubWindowMod` method through the `activeSubWindow()` of the `QMdiArea` and this method actually return a pointer of a `QMdiSubWindow` object, and I can't call my `QMdiSubWindowMod` method through a this pointer of `QMdiSubWindow` object.
How can I call my method through this pointer of `QMdiSubWindow` or have you any tips to make it works? Thank in advance for your answers.

`QMdiSubWindowMod.h`:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include "qcustomlabel.h"

class QMdiSubWindowMod : public QMdiSubWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QMdiSubWindowMod(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
    void setList(QCustomLabel list[80]);
    QCustomLabel* list();
    ~QMdiSubWindowMod();
private:
    QCustomLabel m_list[80];
};
```

`QMdiSubWindowMod.cpp`:

```
#include "qmdisubwindowmod.h"

QMdiSubWindowMod::QMdiSubWindowMod(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
    : QMdiSubWindow(parent, flags)
{

}

QMdiSubWindowMod::~QMdiSubWindowMod()
{
}

QCustomLabel* QMdiSubWindowMod::list()
{
    QCustomLabel *list = new QCustomLabel[80];
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) list[i] = m_list[i];
    return list;
}

void QMdiSubWindowMod::setList(QCustomLabel list[80])
{
    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
    {
        m_list[i] = list[i];
    }
}
```

When I write the argument (I don't have any problem here):

```
QMdiSubWindowMod *onglet = new QMdiSubWindowMod(m_mainArea);
onglet->setList(list);
```

Where I need to read the method(.cpp):

```
QCustomLabel *list[80];
QMdiSubWindowMod *onglet = m_mainArea->activeSubWindow(); //Problem here because of the type of return which is a QMdiSubWindow and not a QMdiSubWindowMod
```

Comment: Show a minimized version of you code that allows us to reproduce the problem. As your problem appears to be a design issue, Ideally remove all Qt-specific stuff. Also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QMdiSubWindowMod *onglet = static_cast<QMdiSubWindowMod*>( m_mainArea->activeSubWindow() );
```

That assumes you **know** at the time the code is written that the object returned will have the correct run-time type.  If getting the wrong object were possible, you should use `dynamic_cast` and then test the result of that cast.